# Swift: display arrayobject to tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

im trying to dispaly array object  come from api response as [[String: Any]] at table view 
and thats my struct

```
class CategoriesDep: NSObject {

    var depName: String
    var depImage: String
    var subName = [subData]()

    init?(dict: [String: JSON]) {

        guard let image = dict["main_department_image"]?.imagePath, !image.isEmpty else { return nil }

        self.depImage = image
        self.depName = (dict["main_department_name"]?.string)!




    }

    struct subData {
        var dep: String
        init(dic: [String: Any]) {
            self.dep = dic["sub_department_name"] as! String

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put your jason response here?

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya  that is my response "sub_depart" :    [  {
    "sub_depart" : [
      {
        "sub_department_name" : "hos",
        "sub_department_id" : "6",
        "sub_department_image" : "23.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "main_department_id" : "2",
    "main_department_name" : "main ",
    "main_department_image" : "14.jpg"
  },  
    ],

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code to parse your json

```
class CategoriesDep: NSObject {
    var depName: String
    var depImage: String
    var subName = [subData]()

    init?(dict: [String: Any]) {

        guard let image = dict["main_department_image"] as? String, !image.isEmpty else { return nil }

        self.depImage = image
        self.depName = (dict["main_department_name"] as? String)!
        subName = []
        for subDict in (dict["sub_depart"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []){
            subName.append(subData(dic: subDict))
        }

    }

}
struct subData {
     var dep: String
     var image :String
     var id : String
     init(dic: [String: Any]) {
          self.dep = dic["sub_department_name"] as! String
          self.image = dic["sub_department_image"] as! String
          self.id = dic["sub_department_id"] as! String
     }
}
```

and if you want to access subdata struct out side of CategoriesDep  class then declare structure outside CategoriesDep class

Parse your given json Respoise like

```
       let json =  [
            [ "sub_depart" : [
                [ "sub_department_name" : "hos", "sub_department_id" : "6", "sub_department_image" : "23.jpg"
                ]
                ],
              "main_department_id" : "2",
              "main_department_name" : "main ",
              "main_department_image" : "14.jpg"
            ],
            ]
        var catDepart : [CategoriesDep] = []
        for dict in json {
            catDepart.append(CategoriesDep(dict: dict)!)
        }
        print(catDepart[0].subName[0].dep)
```

Comment: i tried your answer.but unfortunately it didnt work.maybe i did something wrong..look i declare the struct in vc to var data = [categoriesDep.subData]() and when i try to display it print  word dep

Comment: you need to declare struct  out side class

Comment: yes you need to put top of model class or any other place out side model class 
i updated my answer Please check

Comment: Still the same unfortunately.and there's two errors i should comment the depname and img bc i was cast res json but u changed to any and tried to fix but give me nil nut tried ur answer only without display those but still have the same issue that print word dep only

Comment: I checked my answer and it run fine for me also i added answer how to parse your give  json.

Comment: Thanks my friend.it's working fine now. I really appreciate your help.u made my day❤️

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Codabel` protocol to be more swifty ;) and cleaning up the code.

```
let jsonString = "[{\"sub_depart\" : [ {\"sub_department_name\" : \"hos\", \"sub_department_id\" : \"6\", \"sub_department_image\" : \"23.jpg\" } ], \"main_department_id\" : \"2\", \"main_department_name\" : \"main \", \"main_department_image\" : \"14.jpg\"}]"

struct CategoriesDep: Codable {

    let mainDepartmentName: String
    let mainDepartmentImage: String
    let mainDepartmentId: String
    var subDepart: [SubData] = []
}

struct SubData: Codable {

    let subDepartmentName: String
    let subDepartmentImage: String
    let subDepartmentId: String
}



if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    var departments: [CategoriesDep]? = try? decoder.decode([CategoriesDep].self, from: jsonData)

    ...

}
```

Note the `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` here which is mapping the underscore (snake_case) API property names to your camelCase ones.

If you need different property names you have to implement `CodingKeys` enum to map them.

For more detailed information check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).